# How to perform a power analysis using a prior beta coefficient from multiple regression as an effect size?

Tags: regression, statistical-power

I am performing a power analysis for a planned study. The previous effect sizes I see reported in the literature are all beta coefficients from multiple regression.

It looks like power analysis calculators online use f squared as an effect size (i.e. https://www.danielsoper.com/statcalc/calculator.aspx?id=1) and I cannot find one that uses beta coefficients instead.

Comment: Why not use simulations to determine your power?

Comment: Frankly, don't know how to use simulations to determine power

Comment: Would section 4.3 of http://www.gpower.hhu.de/fileadmin/redaktion/Fakultaeten/Mathematisch-Naturwissenschaftliche_Fakultaet/Psychologie/AAP/gpower/GPower31-BRM-Paper.pdf cover what you need?  It's worth checking out, as is http://users.stat.umn.edu/~helwig/notes/espa-Notes.pdf (especially the last part).

Comment: This could be useful too: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/gpower/multiple-regression-power-analysis/.

Comment: The above references will not help directly with your problem, but this article looks promising: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0197245698000373?via%3Dihub. Unfortunately, it's behind a pay wall.  There is software that comes with the article: http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/PowerSampleSize.

Answer (score 2):

Power analysis for multivariate regressions is easily done using simulations. If you are comfortable with working in R, Alex Coppock has a nice guide on how to use simulations for power analysis at the EGAP website. See [10 Things to Know About Statistical Power](https://web.archive.org/web/20180630024717/http://egap.org/methods-guides/10-things-you-need-know-about-statistical-power), and [Power Analysis Simulations in R](https://web.archive.org/web/20181211055629/http://egap.org/content/power-analysis-simulations-r).